# BASH: how to detect a file that entered the dir the last? (not timestamp)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My question is how to detect a file that has entered the directory the last. (not with creation/modification timestamp)

Usecase:
My scripts must use the files that has been restored from a backup. (if relevant the restoration process takes about 10 minutes). But this file is not necessarily the LATEST in directory. 
EG:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1   user user    670660 Oct 25 09:21    file1
-rw-r--r--. 1   user user        0  Oct 29 11:00    file3
-r--r--r--. 1   user user  37031332 Oct 29 11:56    file4 # <--the LATEST file
-rw-r--r--. 1   user user        0  Oct 30 12:00    file5
-rwx------. 1   user user   6980628 Oct 31 12:47    file6
```

It is possible that the same file already existed in the directory, and been overridden. The solution i'm looking for should detect this case as well.

P.S. - timestamp options always take me to the NEWEST (or last modified) file. Not my case.
Thanks.

Comment: If you need to track changes during backup restore, you can monitor changes in the directory with inotifywait, using create and moved_to events.

Comment: @Vasan There are only a fininte number of available inodes. On an old enough (or well-used enough) file system, eventually a new file could receive a smaller inode than one held by an older file. Treat inodes as an unordered set of tags that are represented by digit strings, not numbers.

Comment: @faceless : I don't quite understand what you mean by "has entered last", but maybe this would work: Record a list of all files in the directory before the restore. Restore the files. Make a list of all files after the restore, and see whether some files have been added. Maybe these are the "entered last" you were refering to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to determine the last file that entered the directory *after the fact*, but can afford to monitor the directory continuously, you could use the Linux kernel's [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) API, and the [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) tool from the `inotify-tools`.

In your case, you'll want to monitor the `moved_to` and `created` events:

```
inotifywait -q -m -e moved_to -e create --format %f /path/to/dir | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do
        echo "last file that entered dir: $file"
    done
```

---

In case you can **wrap your backup restore procedure with some setup and teardown code**, you could start monitoring the target dir with `inotifywait` just before backup restore, and then stop & read the last file that entered the target after restore finishes.

A simple demo, where backup restore is replaced with manual file creation:

```
#!/bin/bash
# target dir, assuming it exists
dir=/tmp/bucket

# setup $dir monitoring in background
list=$(mktemp)
coproc inotifywait -q -m -e moved_to -e create --format %f "$dir" >"$list"

# kill the monitor on backup restore done, and/or on script exit
wrapup() {
    [[ $COPROC_PID ]] && kill -INT "$COPROC_PID" && last=$(tail -n1 "$list") && rm "$list"
}
trap 'wrapup' USR1 EXIT

# simulated "restore from backup" to $dir
rm -f "$dir/xyz"; touch "$dir/xyz"

# kill the monitor, read the last file, and clean-up
kill -USR1 $$

# do something with that last file
echo "Last file in $dir was $last"
```

Comment: thank you, but I need the files to be detected right after the fact of restoration.

Comment: If you control the backup restore start, check my edit. You can start/stop monitoring just before/after restore, and then simply read out the last file that entered the target dir during restore.